# Why doesn't SpringBoot keep running when I use SBT?

Tags: spring-boot, sbt

I have a simple SBT project that uses Spring boot. The `build.sbt` looks like this...

```
scalaVersion := "3.2.2"
organization := "..."
name := "CalBackend"
version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
description := "Backend service for my scheduling system"
organizationHomepage := ...
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-web" % "3.0.6",
  "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-security" % "3.0.6",
  "com.auth0" % "auth0" % "2.1.0",
  "com.auth0" % "java-jwt" % "4.4.0",
)
```

But when I run sbt run It seems to work then just end...

```
This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.
2023-04-22T14:29:10.954-04:00  INFO 3884 --- [bt-bg-threads-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1229fc27, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager
IntegrationFilter@7fce4306, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1798cd37, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@15133278, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@19490b9d, org.springframework.security.web.authenticati
on.logout.LogoutFilter@60b956bc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@16318669, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@1754e30c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.Default
LogoutPageGeneratingFilter@52e786bf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@68f0af53, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7fd3249, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@513e797, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3d4d2b4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@310377ed, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@48ba570e]
2023-04-22T14:29:11.003-04:00  INFO 3884 --- [bt-bg-threads-1] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-04-22T14:29:11.011-04:00  INFO 3884 --- [bt-bg-threads-1] com.secondave.Application$package$       : Started Application.package. in 2.939 seconds (process running for 10.519)
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Apr 22, 2023, 2:29:11 PM
```

What am I missing? How do I keep it listening on the port?

Comment: It works fine when I use IJ to run :-/

Answer (score 0):

I got it to stay running with the tilda like `sbt ~run`. If someone can link to the docs for this feature that would be awesome.